# Having problems with files that have been moved?

Tags: windows-7

So this might be tough to explain, but I'll do my best.

I have a folder that has 10 sub-folders inside it.
I wanted them sorted by department, so I made 2 new folders, and moved 8 of the original sub-folders to one of the new sub-folders, and moved the other 2 to the other 'new' sub-folder.
All the old sub-folders are now separated into the 2 new sub-folders, but the originals remain, even after I moved them.(they are now in 2 places, the new sub-folders, and in the original folder)
I try to delete the old sub-folders but it says I can't delete them while I'm connected to the server.

Any thoughts on why this is?  Does my question even make sense?  I hope so!

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual error message you get when you try to delete them?

Comment: If you just dragged and dropped then you just likely just copied the folders you didn't move them.  Do you have permission to delete these folders/files?

Comment: Well I just tried to delete a file(yes I have permission, I am the admin), and it is saying "Could not find this item.  This is no longer located in G:\foldername\foldername.  Verify the item's location and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging the folders in to another folder will copy the content in to the new folder and it won't moved the data in older source location. Also regarding the delete issue please try opening the command prompt with administrator privileges and try deleting the folders with the command below.

```
  RD /S /Q "directory path" (or) RMDIR /S /Q "directory path"
```

Note : If the folder is opened by some other user in another RDP (or) by any application then you can not delete the folders.